# Border gutters and center icon with grid layout

Tags: html, css, layout, css-grid

```css
.hero__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
}

.vertical-line {
  height: 169px;
  width: 0.5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.horizontal-line {
  width: 300px;
  height: 0.5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero__grid">
  <div class="hero__grid-cell"></div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell">
    <div class="vertical-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell"></div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell">
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell">
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell"></div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell">
    <div class="vertical-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make this effect:
[image]

At first I'm just trying to make:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
```

and somehow put there those lines and an icon, but it seems to not work eventually.
What I was thinking to do is to make a grid 3x3 so it would be :

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
```

And in auto (2nd) row and column divs just put those content but it doesn't look right to me. I know CSS is no perfect, so maybe it is actually the best way to handle it?

1. How can I make a border (or just lines) between grid cells to make such effect?
   I've tried `border-bottom` but it takes full width/height.
2. How to put the heart icon between those in the center of the borders?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D - I've included small code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses [`grid-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) for gutters between rows and columns.
The heart icon is [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) absolutely and [transformed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) up and left by half its size.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.hero__grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2.4em;
  width: 500px;
}

.vertical-line,
.horizontal-line {
  background-color: #BBB;
}

.vertical-line {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.5px;
}

.horizontal-line {
  height: 0.5px;
}

.hero__grid-cell {
  position: relative;
}

.cell-content {
  padding: 0.8em 0;
}

.hero__grid-cell .far {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #e56260;
  font-size: 2.4em;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 0 0 0.3em;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 0;
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="hero__grid">
  <div class="hero__grid-cell cell-content">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell">
    <div class="vertical-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell cell-content">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell">
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell">
    <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell cell-content">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell">
    <div class="vertical-line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero__grid-cell cell-content">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **gap (grid-gap)**
> The gap CSS property sets the gaps (gutters) between rows and columns. It is a shorthand for row-gap and column-gap.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much. I've done this without grid-gap but your idea seems a lot easier!